# PDFminer.six error while extracting data from pdf

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract data from  a PDF file using pdfminer.six.. I have downloaded the sample  code form this package and installed using "pip install pdfminer.six" and I am testing it and stopped with this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "pdf2txt.py", line 11, in <module>
import pdfminer.high_level
 File "C:\xxx\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
  packages\pdfminer\high_level.py", line 11, in <module>
from .pdfdocument import PDFDocument
    File "C:\xxx\uxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\pdfminer\pdfdocument.py", line 26, in <module>
from .pdftypes import PDFObjectNotFound
    ImportError: cannot import name 'PDFObjectNotFound'
```

and my code pdf2txt.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

 import sys
 import logging
 import six
 import pdfminer.settings
 pdfminer.settings.STRICT = False
 import pdfminer.high_level
 import pdfminer.layout
 from pdfminer.image import ImageWriter
 from io import StringIO


  def extract_text(files=[], outfile='-',
        _py2_no_more_posargs=None,  # Bloody Python2 needs a shim
        no_laparams=False, all_texts=None, detect_vertical=None, 
        word_margin=None, char_margin=None, line_margin=None, 
        boxes_flow=None, # LAParams
        output_type='text', codec='utf-8', strip_control=False,
        maxpages=0, page_numbers=None, password="", scale=1.0, rotation=0,
        layoutmode='normal', output_dir=None, debug=False,
        disable_caching=False, **other):
if _py2_no_more_posargs is not None:
    raise ValueError("Too many positional arguments passed.")
if not files:
    raise ValueError("Must provide files to work upon!")

# If any LAParams group arguments were passed, create an LAParams object and
# populate with given args. Otherwise, set it to None.
if not no_laparams:
    laparams = pdfminer.layout.LAParams()
    for param in ("all_texts", "detect_vertical", "word_margin", "char_margin", "line_margin", "boxes_flow"):
        paramv = locals().get(param, None)
        if paramv is not None:
            setattr(laparams, param, paramv)
else:
    laparams = None

imagewriter = None
if output_dir:
    imagewriter = ImageWriter(output_dir)

if output_type == "text" and outfile != "-":
    for override, alttype in (  (".htm", "html"),
                                (".html", "html"),
                                (".xml", "xml"),
                                (".tag", "tag") ):
        if outfile.endswith(override):
            output_type = alttype

if outfile == "-":
    outfp = sys.stdout
    if outfp.encoding is not None:
        codec = 'utf-8'
else:
    outfp = open(outfile, "wb")


for fname in files:
    with open(fname, "rb") as fp:
        pdfminer.high_level.extract_text_to_fp(fp, **locals())
return outfp


 def main(args=None):
import argparse
P = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
P.add_argument("files", type=str, default=None, nargs="+", help="Files to 
 process.")
P.add_argument("-d", "--debug", default=False, action="store_true", 
help="Debug output.")
P.add_argument("-p", "--pagenos", type=str, help="Comma-separated list of 
 page numbers to parse. Included for legacy applications, use -P/--page- 
 numbers for more idiomatic argument entry.")
P.add_argument("--page-numbers", type=int, default=None, nargs="+", 
 help="Alternative to --pagenos with space-separated numbers; supercedes - 
 -pagenos where it is used.")
P.add_argument("-m", "--maxpages", type=int, default=0, help = "Maximum 
     pages to parse")
P.add_argument("-P", "--password", type=str, default="", help = 
     "Decryption password for PDF")
 P.add_argument("-o", "--outfile", type=str, default="-", help="Output 
   file (default/'-' is stdout)")
P.add_argument("-t", "--output_type", type=str, default="text", help = 
 "Output type: text|html|xml|tag (default is text)")
P.add_argument("-c", "--codec", type=str, default="utf-8", help = "Text 
    encoding")
P.add_argument("-s", "--scale", type=float, default=1.0, help = "Scale")
P.add_argument("-A", "--all-texts", default=None, action="store_true", 
  help="LAParams all texts")
P.add_argument("-V", "--detect-vertical", default=None, 
action="store_true", help="LAParams detect vertical")
P.add_argument("-W", "--word-margin", type=float, default=None, help = 
  "LAParams word margin")
P.add_argument("-M", "--char-margin", type=float, default=None, help = 
 "LAParams char margin")
P.add_argument("-L", "--line-margin", type=float, default=None, help = 
  "LAParams line margin")
P.add_argument("-F", "--boxes-flow", type=float, default=None, help = 
    "LAParams boxes flow")
P.add_argument("-Y", "--layoutmode", default="normal", type=str, 
   help="HTML Layout Mode")
P.add_argument("-n", "--no-laparams", default=False, action="store_true", 
    help = "Pass None as LAParams")
P.add_argument("-R", "--rotation", default=0, type=int, help = "Rotation")
P.add_argument("-O", "--output-dir", default=None, help="Output directory 
  for images")
P.add_argument("-C", "--disable-caching", default=False, 
   action="store_true", help="Disable caching")
P.add_argument("-S", "--strip-control", default=False, 
 action="store_true", help="Strip control in XML mode")
A = P.parse_args(args=args)

if A.page_numbers:
    A.page_numbers = set([x-1 for x in A.page_numbers])
if A.pagenos:
    A.page_numbers = set([int(x)-1 for x in A.pagenos.split(",")])

imagewriter = None
if A.output_dir:
    imagewriter = ImageWriter(A.output_dir)

if six.PY2 and sys.stdin.encoding:
    A.password = A.password.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)

if A.output_type == "text" and A.outfile != "-":
    for override, alttype in (  (".htm",  "html"),
                                (".html", "html"),
                                (".xml",  "xml" ),
                                (".tag",  "tag" ) ):
        if A.outfile.endswith(override):
            A.output_type = alttype

if A.outfile == "-":
    outfp = sys.stdout
    if outfp.encoding is not None:
        # Why ignore outfp.encoding? :-/ stupid cathal?
        A.codec = 'utf-8'
else:
    outfp = open(A.outfile, "wb")

## Test Code
outfp = extract_text(**vars(A))
outfp.close()
return 0
```

if **name** == '**main**': sys.exit(main())

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have given all the code.. can u check once please

Comment: Check this Github [link](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/issues/95)

Comment: I have checked this too..NO use.